# Can Spring Boot @Import annotation be used without @Configuration tag

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, annotations

`@Import` annotation in `Spring` is used in order to group configurations.

I know that the standard syntax for this annotation looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ Manager.class, Programmer.class })
class WorkerConfiguration {
}
```

But I am wondering is it possible to use `@Import` annotation to import a group of those annotations outside of a configuration file(maybe in the main file).

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ Manager.class, Programmer.class })
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Import Javadoc :](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html)

> Indicates one or more component classes to import — typically
> @Configuration classes.

`@Import` is often used in the context of a class annotated with `@Configuration` class to include some declared beans in `@Configuration` in another one.  But it also works with composite annotations that contains among other annotations the `@Configuration` one.
And in Spring Boot it turns out that several annotations include  `@Configuration`:

For example [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) that you ask to is also composed (among other things) of a `@Configuration` annotation :

> Indicates a configuration class that declares one or more @Bean
> methods and also triggers auto-configuration and component scanning.
> **This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring
> @Configuration**, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.

So yes what you want to do is valid.